# How to disable tap highlighting without -webkit-tap-highlight-color?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser

I have some elements on my page that can be clicked/tapped. On tap, there happens this thing called "tap highlight" which highlights the element you just tapped. I want to disable this highlighting. So currently, I'm setting the tap highlight color to transparent:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Is there an alternative to `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`? Can I just circumvent the whole highlighting by using specific elements like `<a>` instead of `<div>` or something?